# Using PS to query SQL for list of users, then disable Active Directory accounts?

Tags: sql, powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to use Powershell to query SQL database for a list of suspended users, pipe into a variable, then use that to loop through and disable those AD accounts.  Here's the code I'm using... note I'm just trying to write the output now instead of making a change so I don't do anything I regret.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Users = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance 'SERVER' -Database 'NAME' -Query "SELECT EmployeeID, 
EmployeeStatus FROM [NAME].[dbo].[employee] WHERE EmployeeStatus = 'S'"

foreach ($user in $users)
{
    Get-ADUser -Filter "EmployeeID -eq '$($user.EmployeeID)'" `
    -SearchBase "OU=Logins,DC=domain,DC=com" |
    #Set-ADUser -Identity $Name -Enabled $False
    Write-Verbose $User
}
```

The SQL query is working fine, but when I run the loop it's giving this error:

> Write-Verbose : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for
>   the command either because the 
>       command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline
>   input.

Am I just formatting this incorrectly?  Or is there another way I should be thinking of this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Set-ADUser` is commented out. `Write-Verbose` is getting the pipeline input but cannot bind it to `-Message` because `$user` is positionally bound to it. Another problem is that values piped into `Set-ADUser` bind to the `-Identity` parameter. However, you are manually supplying a value to `-Identity` while wanting to pipe data to it. This is a discrepancy. You should pick one or the other.

Comment: Thanks, those changes did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to find inactive user accounts in Active Directory, you can use the `Search-ADAccount cmdlet`. You need to do this use the `“-AccountInActive”` parameter with `Search-ADAccount`.

PowerShell command below:

```
Search-ADAccount –AccountInActive –TimeSpan 120:00:00:00 –ResultPageSize 2000 –ResultSetSize $null | ?{$_.Enabled –eq $True} | Select-Object Name, SamAccountName, DistinguishedName | Export-CSV “C:\Temp\InActiveADUsers.CSV” –NoTypeInformation
```

I have given timespan for 120days and export the list into csv file.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I'm doing here.  I'm comparing AD accounts to a SQL table to find which accounts should be disabled based on their status (which is pulled from elsewhere).